# Getting categories assigned to a related entry when using {parents}

Tags: categories, related-entries

I'm displaying some related entries by means of the {parents} tag pair. Whilst I can get all the field information as I need it doesn't seem possible to display the categories that are assigned to the related entry.

I've tried

```
{parents}
    {parents:categories backspace="2"}{parents:category_name}{/parents:categories}
{/parents}
```

and many other combinations - but I only seem able to get it to display the tags themselves.

Does anyone have an idea for this (which ideally doesn't involve embeds).

Comment: Are you closing the tags correctly? Did you write the wrong code just here? `{/parents:category}`, right?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing! Shouldn't it be just `{parents}{parents:category_name}{/parents}` or `{parents}{category_name}{/parents}`  ?

Comment: Also, if you can't find a solution there seems to be an add-on: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/category-parents (no solution may be the reason this add-on exists?)

Comment: Yes that's a typo in my question :) Will correct it now.

Comment: Natetronn, you need the categories tag pair so it loops through, and displays all the categories. I tested your suggestion anyway and it doesn't work.

Comment: That add on is a different issue. That gets info about category parents. What I'm trying to do is get category information about a related entry.

Comment: Your syntax should work correctly, so it must be something else. Are you nesting this inside Stash? If the tags are outputting directly it means they're not being parsed, so try increasing Stash's `parse_depth`.

Comment: Nope, not inside anything. All of the other field tags I'm outputting work correctly. It's just the category tags that don't work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I need to do the same thing.